# Pdf to text with line breaks USING PHP

Tags: php, pdftotext

i want to convert PDF to text also line breaks as in PDF.
the code is working fine but without line break.
i am using P.H.P Library.

```
    <?php
    include ('lib/PdfToText.phpclass');
    $pdf=new PdfToText('sample.pdf');
    $string="Hello";
    $data=$pdf->Text;
    echo $data;
    ?>
```

Comment: If you're outputting this in a browser, try using [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) like this: `echo nl2br($data);` to convert line breaks into `<br />` (since browsers don't show ordinary line breaks.)

Comment: Wao Thanks Sir Love you it is fixed.